# Java (beginner): Cannot find symbol in Math class

Tags: java, class, math, import, symbols

guys. I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and I just can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I've done some research, but for others it was stuff like uppercase typos. I didn't cut it with me. Here's the entire code:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Threesix_RasmusDS
{
   public static void smallerAbsVal()
   {     

      int a = 4;
      int b = 9;

      System.out.println(Math.abs(a, b));
      System.out.println(Math.min(a, b));    

}
//End of smallerAbsVal

}
//End of class
```

Comment: Did you go through the [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class API?

Comment: Off topic: Classes from the `java.lang` package are imported by default so the import statement can be removed here

Answer (score 2):

As per the javadoc, [`Math#abs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29) only takes one argument, so it needs to be either  `Math.abs(a)` or `Math.abs(b)`. If youre looking for the smallest absolute value then that would be

```
System.out.println(Math.min(Math.abs(a), Math.abs(b)));
```